# Proving that a certain language is or is not regular using pumping lemma

Tags: automata, pumping-lemma

I have a language defined by

$L = \{ a^{m}b^{n}:m,n \in  N_{0}\}$

This means I have 3 cases:

- $1) \ m > n$
- $2) \ m < n$
- $3) \ m = n$

So I have to prove it in 3 different cases.

Taking case 1 where $m > n$ :

I can choose language such as

$$w = a^{p+1}b^{p}$$

Let's choose $p = 2$.

We have 3 different decompositions for $aaabb$.

$x = \varepsilon \ \text{or} \ x = a  \ \text{or} \ x = \varepsilon$

$y = aa \ \text{or} \ y = a  \ \text{or} \ y = a$

$z = abb \ \text{or} \ z = abb \ \text{or} \ z = aabb$

We can write it in the following way

$$a^{k}a^{l}a^{j}b^{p}$$

where $k \ge 0 , l \ge 1 , j \ge 0 $  and $ l + k \le p + 1 , l + k + j = p + 1$

Which means when I choose index $i = 0$ such as $xy^{i}z = xy^{0}z$

I have now

$$a^{k}a^{0}a^{j}b^{p}$$

and this means that

$ k + l + k \le p $ thus language $w$ does not belong to language $L$ and is not regular ( the other 2 cases are similar; i only want to check if my undertanding is correct).

It this correct or did i misunderstood any concept of pumping lemma? 
Also, what is the best way to choose $p$?

Thanks for answers and help!

Comment: I have tried to better a little your text. Think in particular to place between dollar signs **all** mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is difficult to understand, but it seems like you are trying to show that $L$ is not regular by first considering the language $L' = \{a^mb^n \mid m > n\}$. But the problem is that while a pumped up word from $L'$ might not be in $L'$, it can still be in $L$.

To make matters worse, the langeuage $L$ is regular. Consider e.g. the regular grammar with starting symbol $L$ and the rules $L \to aL | B$ and $B \to bB | \varepsilon$.